In C++, how to destroy a thread started with class member function and waiting on epoll properly?
As the question says, I have an class. Pesudo code is as following:
class MyClass
{
  MyClass() 
  { 
    epoll_fd = epoll_create(0);

    /*start a thread with MyClass::threadFunc() here */ 
    mythread = std::thread( &MyClass::threadFunc, this );
  }

  void threadFunc()
  {
    while( true )
    {
      int numEvents = epoll_wait( epoll_fd, ... );
      // some processing here
    }
  }

  ~MyClass()
  {
    mythread.join();
  }

  std::thread mythread;
  int epoll_fd;
}

int main()
{
  MyClass inst;

  // some processing

  return 0;
}

I would like to have the thread started in the constructor and end in the destructor. However, the thread has an while loop and waiting for events. Hence the join() would never return, would it? I wonder what's the best practice to end the thread execution in this case?
If I use a flag to let the while loop quit, it would only work when the epoll_wait returns. If there is no event, then the program stuck at join(), right? So in this case, do I have to add a wake up fd into the epoll monitor list and manually send a event to itself before calling join()?

use a condition variable to notify the thread that it needs to stop.

Instead of pseudo code, extract a [mcve], which would demonstrate much better what the problem is. Point is, I believe your question is how to unblock a thread that's blocked in epoll_wait(), right? That would have nothing to do with classes or member functions.

MyClass:threadFunc must do some kind of co-operative cancellation.

Also your epoll_wait must NOT be a block function. You might need a second thread to fill a queue with received data (producer) and your threadFunc will then be a consumer.


I wonder what's the best practice to end the thread execution in this case?

Tell the thread to exit and then join it. The mechanism is up to you.
You could:

add a file descriptor to the interest list which you can use to wake up the poll (eg. a pipe, or eventfd, or whatever)
interrupt epoll_wait with a signal, after adding appropriate signal masks and logic for handling EINTR
switch to using epoll_pwait and send that a signal
add a timeout to your poll and check an (appropriately-synchronized) boolean variable to see if the thread should keep running
etc.


The list should include: create a pipe, add the read end to the epoll set and write a byte to the write end from the signalling thread... as that's arguably one of the most common ways to wake up an epoll loop.

eventfd is better than a pipe if all you want to do is wake the epoll_wait

interrupt epoll_wait with a signal, after adding appropriate signal masks and logic for handling EINTR  That can be tough to do in any complex setting such as a multithreaded process or in library code where there may be restrictions on changing any signal handling.  You'd also likely need to a.dd some other "time to quit" state to protect against spurious wakeups.

As your thread is using epoll(), it's useful to acknowledge that you're doing either Actor Model or Communicating Sequential Processes programming, and you're using epoll() as a reactor.
The reason why this is useful is because it's kind of pointing the way for how this thread (and anything else that interracts with it) should work. In essence, it's a very good idea to keep to one idea, i.e. use epoll() also include a file descriptor for an IPC pipe down which thread control commands can be sent. If the only command you need is "quit", then the receipt of, well, anything can be taken to mean that. As the answer from Useless (no doubt an entirely inaccurate handle for the contributor?) says, the thread quits and then the initiator uses join() to wait until the thread actually terminates.
It's a good idea to stick with one idea, because when you start mixed paradigms (e.g. epoll() as a reactor and signals), things can get pretty confusing.
For (an extreme) example, if you're using epoll() to determine when a socket has become ready to read, and then you use asynchronous IO to actually do the read, things can get messy, especially if you start throwing in signals too.

+1 if only for the "keep it simple" approach.  Multithreaded processing is hard enough to do correctly even without extraneous complication.

@AndrewHenle I've done very well out of keeping it simply! I have taken it quite a long way, on occasion. Having a fondness for Actor Model or CSP, I quite like ZeroMQ. However, I also acknowledge that there's a place in C++ for things like std::queue<shared_ptr<>>, etc. So, I have used ZeroMQ to arbitrate between threads using messages to inform which is now entitled to lock a queue and read from it. It sounds complicated, but having constructs like std::queue<<shared_ptr<>> woven alongside ZMQ sockets gives the runtime dynamics of the latter with the speed of the former, with memory safety!
